# Can someone please help me convert a 2d map into an isometric map?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, isometric

I'd like to ask for some assistance converting my 2d map imported from a text file into an isometric map format. I have browsed quite a bit, still kind of new to java and i am more of a "look at example code" rather than wriiting myself. ANYTHING would be helpful at this point. I have also looked here >> [How can i convert x-y position to tile x-y for isometric tile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658980/how-can-i-convert-x-y-position-to-tile-x-y-for-isometric-tile) << and here >> [Drawing Isometric game worlds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892811/drawing-isometric-game-worlds?newreg=bbd30fa29c814e73999587d96b78e5de) << i feel like im almost there but i just quite figure it out. Thank you.

```
for(int row = rowOffset; row < rowOffset + numRowsToDraw; row++) {

        if(row >= numRows) break;

        for(int col = colOffset; col < colOffset + numColsToDraw; col++) {

            if(col >= numCols) break;
            if(map[row][col] == 0) continue;

            int rc = map[row][col];
            int r = rc / numTilesAcross;
            int c = rc % numTilesAcross;

            x = (col / Tile_H) + (row / Tile_W);
            y = (row / Tile_W) - (col / Tile_H);

            g.drawImage(
                tiles[r][c].getImage(),

                //(((y / Tile_HH) - (x / Tile_HW)) / 2) + col * tileSize,
                //(((y / Tile_HH) + (x / Tile_HW)) / 2) + row * tileSize,

                //x,

                //y,


                x + col * tileSize,
                y + row * tileSize,
                null
            );

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the formula to convert 2D coordinates in iso coordinates :

For [I,J] coordinates -> (carefull, I-J is something like this : 0, 1 and not raw coordinates(in pixel i mean).

```
I = (y - x) * (tileWidth / 2)
J = (x + y) * (tileHeight / 2)
```

Then you add 2 offsets(top and left to display the map in the center of the screen)

However I'm not sure if your problem was the formula, as I don't code in java.