# Java multidimensional array to c#

Tags: java, c#, multidimensional-array

I need some help converting this multidimensional array from `Java` to `c#`:

```
int[] tileMap = new int[][] {
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {3, 2, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 3, 3}
};
```

I'm working on implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892811/drawing-isometric-game-worlds) Stackoverflow answer on generating isometric worlds in Unity. I know both Java and `c#`, but I lack the knowledge I need on `c#` multidimensional array to do the conversion.

I tried my only guess at converting it:

```
int[,] tileMap = new int[]{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {3, 2, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 3, 3}
};
```

But I can tell that it's not right, and it throws errors.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
int[][] jagged = new int[][] {
    new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3},
    new int[] {3, 2, 1, 0},
    new int[] {0, 0, 1, 1},
    new int[] {2, 2, 3, 3}
};
```

Edit; the above supports jagged arrays. For non-jagged multidimensional arrays, from HungPV's comment:

```
var tileMap = new int[,] {
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {3, 2, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 1, 1},
    {2, 2, 3, 3}
};
```

You use them differently, as well:

`var res = jagged[0][1];`
vs
`var res = tileMap[0,1];`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `,` in `new int[]`

Try like this

```
int[,] tileMap = new int[,]{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {3, 2, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 3, 3}
};
```

Comment: That did it :) I found it a few seconds ago from @HungPV's comment. Will accept when it lets me in 6 minutes

Comment: A Java jagged array converts to a C# jagged array (as per Rob's answer). Don't know why so many seem to want to convert these to the C#-specific multidimensional array.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I found more info, so I marked Rob's answer as correct as I realized the multidimensional array was not right. I hadn't known of jagged arrays before, they seem quite useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize this way.

```
int[,] tileMap = new int[4, 4]{
        {0, 1, 2, 3},
        {3, 2, 1, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 1},
        {2, 2, 3, 3}
};
```

`Size` is not mandatory, you can even use `int[,]`